# Converting String (-) to Double in C#

Tags: c#

Is it possible to convert a string value to double?

For example: double datatype used to display `0.00` right?
Now, what I want to output is if the value or result is equal to `0.00` then that value should be converted to a hyphen `-`.

```
if (value == 0)
{
    x = "-";
}
```

then display x should be converted to double again since I use double in `Crystal Report`.

Here is my code that gives an error.

```
TCPS = TotalCPS + PSAmount;
TAPPS = TotalAPPS + PSAmount2;
if (TCPS==0)
{
    TCPS = Convert.ToDouble("-");
}
else if (TCPS > 0)
{
    TCPS = TCPS + 0;
}
row["CPS"] = TCPS;
```

`CPS` here is a `Double` datatype and the value of that `CPS` will be displayed in `Crystal Report` that's why I need to output a Hypen `-` instead of `0.00` in the report. I hope this gives you a more clearer info. Thanks

**EDIT:**
Thank you so much guys! I already figured it out! Here's what I did.

```
            TCPS = TotalCPS + PSAmount;
            TAPPS = TotalAPPS + PSAmount2;
            if (TCPS==0)
            {
                row["CPS"] = "-";
            }
            else if (TCPS > 0)
            {
                row["CPS"] = string.Format("{0:N}", TCPS);
            }
```

I changed the datatype of CPS from double to string and that relieves me from stress..:)
Thank you..

Comment: Where are you having issues? Your snippet would appear to work (assuming you have a properly `else` statement). Parsing would be a similar solution, too.

Comment: You can use this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1hkw6k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
or you can use `double.TryParse()`

Comment: Actually Sir it gives me an error since x should be stored in a variable with a datatype double.

Comment: stackErr,.I'm having difficulty using the double.TryParse() method,.I can't figure out the right code when using that method.

Comment: @James: You could use a string in place of double, especially for *display* on the ui. Try this `double d = 0;
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("0.00;(0.00);-"));`

Comment: How about in windows form Sir??How to do that??

Comment: What are you trying to do here: `TCPS = Convert.ToDouble("-");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
string yourStr = "0.00";
double yourDouble;

if(double.TryParse(yourStr, out yourDouble) == false)
{
    //Couldn't parse input as double. Handle this case
}

if(yourDouble == 0.00)
{
        string x = "-";
}
```

Or you can use the `Convert.ToDouble` if you know that the input will always be a double:

```
string yourStr = "0.00";
double yourDouble = Convert.ToDouble(yourStr);
if(yourDouble == 0)
{
    string x = "-";
}
```

**EDIT**

You cannot do this:

```
TCPS = Convert.ToDouble("-");
```

The hyphen is not a `double`, its a `string` and it cannot be type casted to a double.

**What you are trying to do is not possible. You have to convert the field that has the hyphen to a string field instead of a double field in your report.**

Comment: I'll try this one later. I'll then give you the feedback. Thanks

Comment: @Tdorno Haha I knew I was doing it wrong when I wrote it. I am in the habit of `==false` but then I thought that it might not be a good idea to confuse the OP with more code dealing with error checking so I reverted to `==true`.

Comment: You're right. And I did that already but the problem "for me" is how can I make the result or convert the result to something like this: For example: Result = 1,500.00. That is in double but when converted to string that would be 1500 right? I want to display the string type to 1,500.00,.How to do that?

Comment: @James when you convert the double to a string via `.toString()`, it will be `1,500.00` not `1500`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`double.TryParse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert "-" to 0.00

```
  string x = "-";
  double outPut;
  double.TryParse(x, out outPut);
```

`double.TryParse()` will return `true` if conversion is successfull and `false` if it is not. and return `0.00` to the  out parameter in case of failure conversion. in your case you will get the required output (`0.00`) but actually it is a result of a failure conversion.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var x = value == 0 ? "-" : value.ToString();
// then display x as either
```

Comment: @James This definitely works, unless you expect `x` to be a double (as evidenced by your comments above) - which is simply not possible.

Comment: Maybe I need to reconstruct my code and give this a try. Thanks Sir,.Feedback later.